# Is it possible to disable the video output in a video player but keep the audio enabled?

Tags: sound, video

I sometimes hide the video player and only listen to music. But it still uses the processor, and my computer gets hot.

Is there a way to temporarily disable video output and only play audio, without extraction or conversion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with the default video player on Ubuntu (totem) but with [VLC media player](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/vlc/) you can easily disable the video stream of a media file and only let the audio play (or vice versa):

[image]

With this method settings won't be preserved across different files/loops of the same file. A more permanent solution is disabling video playback from the preferences menu:

[image]

[image]

Comment: one problem with it, it keeps turning video on after each loop, every 19 seconds.

Comment: @michel I added a more permanent solution to my original answer. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: Note: You can use this from the command line as well using `vlc --novideo`. This is especially useful if you're using the ncurses interface, ie. `vlc -I ncurses --novideo`

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that totem allows this. If you use mplayer, there is a command line switch for that purpose: `-novideo`. If the `-novideo` option does not work, you can instead use the `-vo null -vc null` options, and if that fails, you can just choose a nonexistant `-vo` driver. For more details, read the mplayer man page.

```
mplayer -novideo <filename>
mplayer -vo thisoutputdriverdoesntexist <filname>
mplayer -vo null -vc null <filename>
```

Comment: it's also available in vlc and cvlc as `--novideo`, useful when you just want to temporary disable video instead of a 'permanent' setting.

Answer (score 2):

`vlc --no-video <media>;` should do the trick without "permanently" disabling VLC's video-playing capability.